# CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake after downgrading GCC 9.3.0 to 7 for openpose

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, cuda

Do you know how I could fix the following error? It happened after I downgraded from GCC 9.3.0 to 7 using the following commands (with the previous version of GCC I got this error: [CMake: unsupported GNU version -- gcc versions later than 8 are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605972/cmake-unsupported-gnu-version-gcc-versions-later-than-8-are-not-supported)):

```
$ sudo apt remove gcc
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7 -y
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/bin/gcc
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-7 /usr/bin/g++
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
[10889:10881 0:2041] 10:13:10 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ make -j`nproc`
[ 12%] Performing build step for 'openpose_lib'
[  1%] Built target caffeproto
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/util/cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o
[  4%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o
[  5%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o
[  5%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o
[  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o


/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o


CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/util/./cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o


/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o


CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o


CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o


CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o


CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o


CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:86: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_norm_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:79: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_base_data_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:128: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_contrastive_loss_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:499: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/util/cuda_compile_1_generated_math_functions.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:107: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bnll_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:72: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_accuracy_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:93: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_batch_reindex_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:114: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_clip_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:121: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_concat_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:100: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_bias_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:65: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_absval_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:135: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/layers/cuda_compile_1_generated_conv_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:371: src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:112: caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

```
$ nvidia-smi
Wed Jan  6 22:27:38 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.38       Driver Version: 455.38       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 165...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P5     6W /  N/A |    891MiB /  3911MiB |      8%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1232      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                133MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1877      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                434MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2054      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              156MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2426      G   ...gAAAAAAAAA --shared-files      152MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Also:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/cc
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/cc': No such file or directory
22539/31772MB
[30303:30295 0:1999] 02:02:35 Thu Jan 07 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

21803/31772MB
[30303:30295 0:2000] 02:07:43 Thu Jan 07 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

21861/31772MB
[30303:30295 0:2001] 02:07:47 Thu Jan 07 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
21851/31772MB
[30303:30295 0:2002] 02:07:51 Thu Jan 07 [mona@goku:pts/0 +1] ~
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
21851/31772MB
```

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/bin/cc`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works for gcc, as for c++, should I say /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/c++: not found `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-7 /usr/bin/c++`? thank you @RobertCrovella

Comment: @RobertCrovella that worked. Could you please add it as an answer? awesome https://pastebin.com/raw/6SbX7aka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/bin/cc
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-7 /usr/bin/c++
```

Thanks to Robert Crovella for the answer.