# "Error generating file" when install cutorch in luarocks

Tags: cmake

When installing cutorch in luarocks, I get following error:

```
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCTensorIndex.cu.o.Release.cmake:280 (message):
   Error generating file
   /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-2888/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCTensorIndex.cu.o
```

My operating system is Ubuntu18.04. I have also tried to use Ubuntu 20.04. This time I use CUDA toolkit 10.1 update 2, my CUDnn is using v 7.6.5.
My gcc version is 7.5.0 .

I have used the method on the webpage

https://arabelatso.github.io/2020/01/05/Install%20lua5.2%20luarocks%20and%20torch7%20on%20Ubuntu18.0.4%20with%20CUDA9.1/

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you checked other questions with the similar error mesage? E.g. that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618513/cmake-error-at-cuda-compile-1-generated-batch-norm-layer-cu-o-release-cmake-afte

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried your link however it  also shown "CMake Error at THC_generated_THCTensorIndex.cu.o.Release.cmake:280 (message):
  Error generating file
"

Comment: From now on my gcc version is 7.5.0. Still failed to build.